# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2.environment'

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, jinja2

i was trying to implement [flask db - sqlite](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/#id5) . im getting NoModule error with `jinja2.environment`

my jinja2 module is installed in

```
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (2.10.3)
```

the complete traceback

```
PS C:\Users\ramesh> & c:/anaconda/python.exe c:/MyProjects/runs/__init__.py
    PS C:\Users\ramesh> flask init-db
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Anaconda\Scripts\flask-script.py", line 5, in <module>
        from flask.cli import main
      File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        from jinja2 import escape
      File "c:\Anaconda\Scripts\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2.environment'
```

Comment: do you have c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py?  Have you tried updating your jinja module?

Comment: yes it is there and i have the latest version of jinja2

Comment: Hang on a sec..  it's referring to c:\Anaconda\Scripts\jinja2  and not the one in your site-packages one.  perhaps you have jinja2 installed both in the site-packages and in Scripts\?   Perhaps remove the Scripts' version.

Comment: yes i had two jinjas installed i removed the one that had no jinja2.environment module.. thank you